# How can I continuously update React state in a loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a React beginner and I'm trying to understand how I can achieve a real-time updating of my component state. Specifically, I'd like to loop over the bounds of my Board and set the color of a given cell in real time.

When I call the "colorBoard" function, the cells get added to the state but the update never occurs. Is there any way to have the board update cell-by-cell so it looks "live"?

```js
interface AppState {
  // Array of positions denoting white cells in the board
  cells: Position[];
}

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props)
    
    // Initially, the board is all black.
    this.state = {
      coloredCells: []
    }
  }

  addCell = (pos: Position) => {
    this.setState({ coloredCells: [...this.state.coloredCells, pos] })
  }
  

  // colorBoard will ideally live in a separate file and will be 
  // passed a callback to the "addCell" function.
  colorBoard = (addCell: (Position) => void) => {
      for (let r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
          for (let c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
              if (Math.random() > 0.9) {
                  addCell({ row: r, col: c }) 
              }
          }
      }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Board colored={this.state.coloredCells} />
      </div>
    ); 
  }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't update state _for each cell_ - instead define an action that updates all the cells all-at-once.

Comment: While the example simply loops over the cells, I'd like to essentially "carve" a path on a black board using some algorithm. I'd like this to happen in real time so I can use it for demonstrative purposes on how the path carving algorithm works.

Comment: To get updated state after setting state you need to use the `setState` [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

And to update state after a small duration has passed you need to use JavaScript's `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To update the state slowly you can use `setTimeout`.
2. If you need the updated state for each iteration of your loop, then you should pass a function to `this.setState` and not an object. The arguments for the updater function are [guaranteed to be up-to-date](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

> setState(updater, [callback]) // signature for the setState function
>
> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:
>
> (state, props) => stateChange
>
> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed
> to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with
> state.

Please see [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/settimeout-state-update-rc34t?file=/src/App.js) for an example

Answer (score 0):

**From [React Docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Basically, don't call setState in a loop. What's happening here is this.state is returning the previous value, as the pending state update has not been applied yet.